# Updating a Favicon and finding the root directory. Did not install

Tags: wordpress

I was given administrative access to a blog and have been asked to update the favicon. I watched a video and I have done all the steps needed to generate a favicon from an image. The only problem that I have is using FTP to transfer the image to my root directory. I understand where the root directory is theoretically found but the problem is that I didn't install Wordpress. All I was given was administrative access. I'm assuming that the person who created the site has the files on his computer, so only he can update the root directory and place the favicon in it. However, common sense tells me that this assumption has to be wrong or is it?

Should I be asking the site's creator to copy the files to me? This doesn't seem right at all. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an admin access to a live blog then the wordpress files are correctly installed. Check for folders starting by the prefix `wp-` like for instance `wp-content` in your FTP directories. If you can't find any then you are not on the correct FTP server. Now suppose you are on the right FTP server. Put your `.ico` image in the `/wp-content/uploads` folder.

Once done to display the `favicon` go to your **admin panel** in the menu on the left choose the option `Appearance` or `Display` *(I don't know the exact word since I am using it in French but it should be something related to the look of your blog)* Then go to the `editor` option and select the file `header.php` to edit.

And add the following line of code right after the code `<head>`:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/wp-content/uploads/favicon-filename.ico">
```

Save the changes and voilà.